# Repetitive "add folder" problem over visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

#### Description

After upgraded my visual studio code to the latest `version 1.43.1`, I am facing some problem over my add folder tab, it keep on adding new 'add folder button' to the tab each and every time I close and add a new folder.

#### Problem:

https://prnt.sc/rjzrah